# 2048 game - AI can't score more that 256 average

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning, 2048

I'm trying to implement AI for 2048 with MiniMax and Alpha-Beta pruning, based on a snake strategy (see [this](http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~ai/projects/2014/2048Solver/files/report.pdf) paper), which seems to be the best as a single heuristics.

Unfortunately, AI makes 256 in most games, what is not much better than empty cells heuristics. I've already read related topics here, but can't find solution myself.

Here is the code:

```
import math
from BaseAI_3 import BaseAI

INF_P = math.inf

class PlayerAI(BaseAI):
    move_str = {
        0: "UP",
        1: "DOWN",
        2: "LEFT",
        3: "RIGHT"
    }

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.depth_max = 4

    def getMove(self, grid):
        move_direction, state, utility = self.decision(grid)
        act_move = moves.index(move_direction)
        return moves[act_move] if moves else None

    def get_children(self, grid):
        grid.children = []
        for move_direction in grid.getAvailableMoves():
            gridCopy = grid.clone()
            gridCopy.path = grid.path[:]
            gridCopy.path.append(PlayerAI.move_str[move_direction])
            gridCopy.move(move_direction)
            gridCopy.depth_current = grid.depth_current + 1
            grid.children.append((move_direction, gridCopy))
        return grid.children

    def utility(self, state):

        def snake():
            poses = [
                [
                    [2 ** 15, 2 ** 14, 2 ** 13, 2 ** 12],
                    [2 ** 8, 2 ** 9, 2 ** 10, 2 ** 11],
                    [2 ** 7, 2 ** 6, 2 ** 5, 2 ** 4],
                    [2 ** 0, 2 ** 1, 2 ** 2, 2 ** 3]
                ]
                ,
                [
                   [2 ** 15, 2 ** 8, 2 ** 7, 2 ** 0],
                   [2 ** 14, 2 ** 9, 2 ** 6, 2 ** 1],
                   [2 ** 13, 2 ** 10, 2 ** 5, 2 ** 2],
                   [2 ** 12, 2 ** 11, 2 ** 4, 2 ** 3]
                ]
            ]

            poses.append([item for item in reversed(poses[0])])
            poses.append([list(reversed(item)) for item in reversed(poses[0])])
            poses.append([list(reversed(item)) for item in poses[0]])

            poses.append([item for item in reversed(poses[1])])
            poses.append([list(reversed(item)) for item in reversed(poses[1])])
            poses.append([list(reversed(item)) for item in poses[1]])

            max_value = -INF_P
            for pos in poses:
                value = 0
                for i in range(state.size):
                    for j in range(state.size):
                        value += state.map[i][j] * pos[i][j]

                if value > max_value:
                    max_value = value

            return max_value

        weight_snake = 1 / (2 ** 13)

        value = (
            weight_snake * snake(),
        )

        return value

    def decision(self, state):
        state.depth_current = 1
        state.path = []
        return self.maximize(state, -INF_P, INF_P)

    def terminal_state(self, state):
        return state.depth_current >= self.depth_max

    def maximize(self, state, alpha, beta):
        # terminal-state check
        if self.terminal_state(state):
            return (None, state, self.utility(state))

        max_move_direction, max_child, max_utility = None, None, (-INF_P, )
        for move_direction, child in self.get_children(state):
            _, state2, utility = self.minimize(child, alpha, beta)
            child.utility = utility

            if sum(utility) > sum(max_utility):
                max_move_direction, max_child, max_utility = move_direction, child, utility

            if sum(max_utility) >= beta:
                break

            if sum(max_utility) > alpha:
                alpha = sum(max_utility)

        state.utility = max_utility
        state.alpha = alpha
        state.beta = beta

        return max_move_direction, max_child, max_utility

    def minimize(self, state, alpha, beta):
        # terminal-state check
        if self.terminal_state(state):
            return (None, state, self.utility(state))

        min_move_direction, min_child, min_utility = None, None, (INF_P, )
        for move_direction, child in self.get_children(state):
            _, state2, utility = self.maximize(child, alpha, beta)
            child.utility = utility

            if sum(utility) < sum(min_utility):
                min_move_direction, min_child, min_utility = move_direction, child, utility

            if sum(min_utility) <= alpha:
                break

            if sum(min_utility) < beta:
                beta = sum(min_utility)

        state.utility = min_utility
        state.alpha = alpha
        state.beta = beta

        return min_move_direction, min_child, min_utility
```

`grid` is an object, `grid.map` is a two-dimentional array (list of lists).

Do I have any mistakes? How can I imporove the code?

Added game log: https://pastebin.com/eyzgU2dN

Comment: When I play manually I swipe up and left a majority of the time in an effort to keep the blocks sorted with the largest values at the top left. I found swiping down or right as well caused the blocks to get jumbled up more quickly resulting in a lower score. I would swipe  right only when I cannot swipe up or left. And if those 3 are not an option then I'd swipe down immediately followed by an up. ... That's just my strategy.

Comment: codereview might be a better place for this, if this code works and you just want to improve it

Comment: @depperm, code is ok I think, checked it several times

Comment: @GlennFerrie, I'm aware of your strategy, the snake strategy is a problem. May be I'm implementing it wrong?

Comment: @depperm - I completely understand your thinking, and I am guessing it probably wouldn't be *wrong* at Code Review; but this may be one of those questions that legitimately is a reasonable fit at multiple sites (such as gamedev, mentioned in the 2048 tag). The case for it being a Stack Overflow question is that maybe the code *isn't* working, in the sense that it's not behaving as expected. Maybe the algorithm is not implemented correctly, or is misapplied to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the past weekend I've realized that algorithm was not properly implemented. A mistake was in the `minimize()` function, where I search for children in a wrong way - it should be like this:

```
def get_opponent_children(self, grid):
    grid.children = []
    for x in range(grid.size):
        for y in range(grid.size):
            if grid.map[x][y] == 0:
                for c in (2, 4):
                    gridCopy = grid.clone()
                    gridCopy.path = grid.path[:]
                    gridCopy.deep_current = grid.deep_current + 1
                    gridCopy.map[x][y] = c
                    grid.children.append((None, gridCopy))

    return grid.children
```

and corresponding change:

```
for move_direction, child in self.get_opponent_children(state):
```

Now it's ok to hit 1024 and 2048 most of time.